# MS Graph API: One Drive bot authentification (Python)

Tags: authentication, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, bots, microsoft-graph-files

I'm trying to create a bot to access One Drive: I need to download files from One Drive and upload them there with a Python program. I'm struggling to authenticate the bot. I have app id, tenant id and client secret as well as 'app email address' and password. Is there an easy way to access one drive via bot? I've already tried:

- https://github.com/microsoftgraph/python-sample-auth
- https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/python/24.bot-authentication-msgraph

Unfortunately, both methods are not really related to authentification with further one drive usage. Moreover, the first one failed and the second one is too complicated to be used for anything but chat bots. Hope somebody could help me to find the proper solution :)

Comment: Please share the failed error response for the first one with requiestid and timestamp.

Comment: First I get this:

C:\Users\anndenisova\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bottle.py:386: RuntimeWarning: Route <GET /static/<filepath:path>> overwrites a previously defined route
  warnings.warn(msg % (method, rule), RuntimeWarning)
Bottle v0.12.19 server starting up (using WSGIRefServer())...
Listening on http://localhost:5000/
Hit Ctrl-C to quit.

127.0.0.1 - - [09/Jan/2021 18:00:04] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 765
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Jan/2021 18:00:04] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 742

Comment: And after following the link I get:

Error: 500 Internal Server Error
Sorry, the requested URL 'http://localhost:5000/' caused an error:

Template 'homepage.html' not found.

Comment: I don't really understand, how to get request id

Comment: I don't see any issue with graph, adding related tags so that others can help.

Comment: Still you see the issue? If yes share the requestid, timestamp for the Graph API calls reponse.